# jquery animation won't return back when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem in this jquery animation.

to make it brief, the expanded div won't return back when clicked again.

here's a jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/vtaqm3cb/

here's a sample of code that i used in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#div_menu_icon").click(function(){
    var new_size = "250"; //this is the width of the menu when expanded
    var menu_icon_width = "55px";
    var div_menu_open = $("#div_menu").width() >= new_size ? menu_icon_width : new_size ;


    $('#div_menu').animate({ width: div_menu_open, }, {duration:200,queue: false });
    $('#div_menu_icon').animate({ width: div_menu_open }, {duration:200,queue: false });
  });

});
```

please help me to fix this, thanks

EDIT: try to replace the CSS of div_menu with this one in jsfiddle, it works. but the i need the border for my design, so is there a way around to fix it?

```
#div_menu{

background-color:#34495e;
width:100%;
height: calc( 100% - 50px);
}
```

Comment: the div_menu_open, is just a variable name, it doesn't mean it is used when i open it. the weird thing is when i tried to remove the border of div_menu, it works. but that's what i need :<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var expanded = false;    
  var new_size = "250";
  var menu_icon_width = "55";

  $("#div_menu_icon").click(function(){          
      var newWidth = expanded ? menu_icon_width : new_size;          
      $('#div_menu').animate({ width: newWidth }, {duration:200 });
      $('#div_menu_icon').animate({ width: newWidth }, {duration:200 });          
      expanded = !expanded;
  });      
});
```

I don't know why yours isn't working, I'm going to continue to look into it because it'll bug me otherwise. But, at least for now, I've simplified your logic and brought the variables outside of the event handler as I suggested.